# Past simple and continuous.88

Tags: past-simple, past-continuous

When I ask my friend about their previous day I could say

What did you do yesterday?

And he could answer

I played, watched and ate.

Could I say : What were you doing yesterday?
And he answers I was playing, watching and eating?

Are both versions correct and natural?

Comment: I don't think either is particularly natural. You'd say "I played games, watched TV, and ate." Although not sure why you would need to say that you ate - do you often not eat all day? So not sure how best to phrase that. Whether you use simple past or past continuous depends on the nature of the activity and how long it lasts.

Comment: Ok but both versions  are acceptable?

Comment: Perhaps it's a silly question but what does 88 in the title stand for?

Comment: Nothing just a number

Answer (score 1):

Well your friend would probably say what he played. Like did he play video games or did he play football? And he would almost surely say what he watched. At least say "I watched girls in the park" versus "I watched TV", and if the latter, maybe say what programs he watched. He'd probably say what he ate, as everybody eats sometime during the day so just saying "I ate" isn't very informative. Someone might answer in vague generalities if he wanted to make the point that is day was ordinary and boring and he did nothing unusual. But that wasn't the point of your question so whatever.

So real answer: Both tenses are valid and natural. It would not be jarring if the person answered with a different tense than the questoin. Like if you asked, "What did you do yesterday?", no one would be surprised if he answers, "Mostly I was playing video games."

If you are just asking for general information, you would likely say, "What did you do yesterday?" You would only say "What were you doing?" if you were contrasting what he did with some other event. Like, "Why didn't you come to the football game? What were you doing yesterday that was more fun than playing football?"

Comment: Does it always work like that I mean what did you do: last week on Sundatyduring your holidat an so on. Here it's more natural to use simple past right? One more think you said "If you are just asking for general information, you would likely say, "What did you do yesterday?" You would only say "What were you doing?" if you were contrasting what he did with some other event. Like, "Why didn't you come to the football game? What were you doing yesterday that was more fun than playing football?" What if I say where were you doing yesterdy  without any contrast. Is it a little akward but acceptab

Comment: @Duppp It's grammatically correct and would be readily understood. My guess just from anecdotal experience is that it's not very common, few native speakers would say it that way. But no one would be likely to be confused by it or question it.

Comment: thank you so much for the help I really do appreciate the effort. I have two more questions if you don't mind to answer them when you're free. 1 You state that it is more common to say "What did you do yesterday" than " What were you doing yesterdag" when it's just a general inquiry. Does it work the same way with the futute simple and continuous and " what will you do tomorrow" is more common than " what will you be doing tomorrow:?

Comment: 2 when I say: "I played a game, watched TV and cooked". It implies one activity after another but when I use the past continuous it implies that these things happpened at the same time?

Comment: future: Yes, it works the same way. Most native speakers would say, "What will you do tomorrow?"rather than "What will you be doing tomorrow?" But as noted above, both are acceptable and in practice mean the same thing.

Comment: One after the other: Not really. If I said, "Yesterday I played video games and ate some snacks", maybe I played the games and then ate the snacks. Or maybe I played some games, ate some snacks, then played some more games, then ate some more snacks. Maybe I ate snacks while playing video games. No sequences is implied. If you want to say that they happened in a certain order, you could say, "I played video games, THEN I ate some snacks", or other words to specify a sequence.

Comment: thank you very much. Thanks to your feedback I do understand more and more.

Comment: I played for 4 years vs I was playing for 4 years. The past simple is more common here but both versions are acceptable. If I say I was playing for 4 years when I decided to  switch teams then the past continuous is common and natural. Is that right? It works the same way with future continuous and simple. I will play for 4 years vs I will be playing for 4 years. Here simple is more common but again both are acceptable. I will be playing 4 four years when I switch teams then comtinuous is common. Is that right?

Comment: General question about the past then simple is more common What did you do yesterday or last week or last week but continuous is acceptable too right? What were you doing yesterday when I called yoy then continuous is common. I hear people ssying " I will be working next week or next month" isn't simplr more common here?

Comment: Or people say I will be working tomorrow but simple is more common here is that right?